# How to fix javascript reference error: prompt not defined

Tags: javascript, calculator, prompt, referenceerror

I wrote code for simple weight conversion and an annual profit calculator program asking the user for input. When I run the programs in vscode it displays the error "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined."

```
var weight_in_lbs = prompt("Please enter the weight in lbs you wish to convert:");
var pound_to_kg = (weight_in_lbs * .45359237);
console.log("The weight converted in kg is" + " " + pound_to_kg.toFixed(3))`
```

```
var annualSales = prompt("What is the projected total sales amount?");
var salesPrediction = (annualSales * .23);
console.log ("Your annual profit is " + salesPrediction.toFixed(2)) ;
```

Comment: Are you running it in a Node env by any chance?

Comment: @Clarity the OP says it's being run in vscode

Comment: @Pointy that does sound like it's run in the node env then. Unless I'm missing smth.

Comment: kindly give few more details to proceed giving suggestion

Answer (score 2):

`prompt` is not a valid construct in the Node.js runtime (which assumedly is what you are running in through VSCode). It will only work in browser-based JavaScript engines.

There are libraries that offer similar functionality, but you would have to install via NPM and import them into your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, which uses the Electron environment, the `prompt` function is not support as it is UI blocking. See this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/472) for more info.

You will need to run your example in a browser such as in the snippet below.

```js
var weight_in_lbs = prompt("Please enter the weight in lbs you wish to convert:");
var pound_to_kg = (weight_in_lbs * .45359237);
console.log("The weight converted in kg is" + " " + pound_to_kg.toFixed(3))
var annualSales = prompt("What is the projected total sales amount?");
var salesPrediction = (annualSales * .23);
console.log("Your annual profit is " + salesPrediction.toFixed(2));
```